# Undefined array key checkboxes html php

Tags: php, html

i wrote a Filter for a Webshop looking like this:

[image: Filter]

I get them with this code

```
        $ei= $_POST['Ei'];
        $erdnuss= $_POST['Erdnuss'];
        $gluten= $_POST['Gluten'];
        $laktose= $_POST['Laktose'];
        $tomate= $_POST['Tomate'];
if(!empty($ei)){

        $notin=$notin."beschraenkung_zutat.F_BNAME ='Ei' OR ";

        }
        if(!empty($erdnuss)){

        $notin=$notin."beschraenkung_zutat.F_BNAME ='Erdnuss' OR ";

        }
        if(!empty($gluten)){

        $notin=$notin."beschraenkung_zutat.F_BNAME ='Gluten' OR ";

        }
        if(!empty($laktose)){

        $notin=$notin."beschraenkung_zutat.F_BNAME ='Laktose' OR ";

        }
        if(!empty($tomate)){

        $notin=$notin."beschraenkung_zutat.F_BNAME ='Tomate' OR ";

        }
```

When my boxes are unchecked i get this arror MSG:

Warning: Undefined array key "Ei" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\ingredient.php on line 103

When they are checked i recieve no error MSG pls help

I initilasing my form with this code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql='SELECT * FROM beschraenkungen';
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  echo '<form action="?filter=1" method="post">';
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo  '<label>'.$row["BNAME"].'</label><input type="checkbox" name="'.$row["BNAME"].'" >';
  }
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Filter">';
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Can you add full code like how you are submitting filter?

Comment: changed it above ty for help
```

Comment: What you want to do please give details

Answer (score 4):

**Note:**

If a checkbox is unchecked when its form is submitted, there is no value submitted to the server to represent its unchecked state `(e.g. value=unchecked);` the value is not submitted to the server at all.

If you wanted to submit a default value for the checkbox when it is unchecked, you could include an `<input type="hidden">` inside the form with the same name and value, generated by JavaScript perhaps.

try to check if your checkboxes are set in your PHP code as below, Hope it works for you

```
if(isset($_POST['Ei']))
{
  $ei= $_POST['Ei'];
}
if(isset($_POST['Erdnuss']))
{
  $erdnuss= $_POST['Erdnuss'];
}
```